# SQL Server 2000: How to exit a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, control-flow

How can I exit in the middle of a stored procedure?

I have a stored procedure where I  want to bail out early (while trying to debug it). I've tried calling `RETURN` and `RAISERROR`, and the sp keeps on running:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Archive_Session @SessionGUID uniqueidentifier AS

    print 'before raiserror'
    raiserror('this is a raised error', 18, 1)
    print 'before return'
    return -1
    print 'after return'

[snip]
```

I know it keeps running because I encounter an error further down. I don't see any of my **prints**. If I comment out the bulk of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Archive_Session @SessionGUID uniqueidentifier AS

    print 'before raiserror'
    raiserror('this is a raised error', 18, 1)
    print 'before return'
    return -1
    print 'after return'

   /*
     [snip]
   */
```

Then I don't get my error, and I see the results:

```
before raiserror
Server: Msg 50000, Level 18, State 1, Procedure Archive_Session, Line 5
this is a raised error
before return
```

So the question is: how do I bail out of a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Comment: "Welcome to the Hotel California..." =)

Comment: Guh? (padding to make my "Guh?" query at least 15 characters long)

Comment: Oh wait, i get it..."you can never leave".   <IanBoyd slow="true"/>

Comment: That this question even needs to be asked indicates that there's something slightly off about SQL, but then again, it's procedural methodology bolted on the side of a functional language, so what do you expect?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use `RETURN` to stop execution of a stored procedure immediately. Quote taken from [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx):

> Exits unconditionally from a query or
>   procedure. RETURN is immediate and
>   complete and can be used at any point
>   to exit from a procedure, batch, or
>   statement block. Statements that
>   follow RETURN are not executed.

Out of paranoia, I tried yor example and it does output the PRINTs and does stop execution immediately.

Comment: Can you think of any reason why calling `return` would not unconditionally exit from a procedure?

Comment: Be careful return-ing out of a procedure if you've started a transaction or have an open cursor.

Comment: I can't - could you post a full sproc example that when you run it, does not exit immediately on the RETURN? Just so we have an exact example to review

Comment: Would this work in a TRY-CATCH? So if I call RETURN within the TRY, would it then execute the CATCH?

Answer (score 31):

Unless you specify a severity of 20 or higher, `raiserror` will not stop execution.  See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx).

The normal workaround is to include a `return` after every `raiserror`:

```
if @whoops = 1
    begin
    raiserror('Whoops!', 18, 1)
    return -1
    end
```

Comment: "Severity levels from 19 through 25 can only be specified by members of the sysadmin fixed server role or users with ALTER TRACE permissions." From MSDN

Comment: @Forgotten Semicolon: Yeah, so in most cases, `raiserror` wins the prize for the function that functions in a way nobody expects (as well as the golden typo trophy)

Comment: +1. Not really an answer to this question, but "the answer is useful"

Answer (score 12):

Put it in a `TRY/CATCH`.

> When RAISERROR is run with a severity
>   of 11 or higher in a TRY block, it
>   transfers control to the associated
>   CATCH block

Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx).

**EDIT:**  This works for MSSQL 2005+, but I see that you now have clarified that you are working on MSSQL 2000.  I'll leave this here for reference.

Comment: +1 SQL Server 2000, so doesn't help answer my question. But it can be a useful technique for someone trying to do exception handling

Comment: I really like this.  but ... sigh ... something else new to learn.

Answer (score 9):

i figured out why `RETURN` is not unconditionally returning from the stored procedure. The error i'm seeing is while the stored procedure is being **compiled** - not when it's being executed.

Consider an imaginary stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo AS

INSERT INTO ExistingTable
EXECUTE LinkedServer.Database.dbo.SomeProcedure
```

Even though this stord proedure contains an error (maybe it's because the objects have a differnet number of columns, maybe there is a timestamp column in the table, maybe the stored procedure doesn't exist), you can still *save* it. You can save it because you're referencing a linked server.

But when you actually *execute* the stored procedure, SQL Server then *compiles* it, and generates a query plan.

My error is not *happening* on line 114, it is *on* line 114. SQL Server cannot compile the stored procedure, that's why it's failing.

And that's why `RETURN` does not return, because it hasn't even **started** yet.

Comment: of course you should never code an insert without specifying the columns.

Comment: Of course i wanted to code the insert without specifying columns. Now that i have to specify them, additional columns added to the source table will be lost.

Answer (score 5):

This works over here.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Archive_Session
    @SessionGUID int
AS 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        PRINT 'before raiserror'
        RAISERROR('this is a raised error', 18, 1)
        IF @@Error != 0 
            RETURN
        PRINT 'before return'
        RETURN -1
        PRINT 'after return'
    END
go

EXECUTE dbo.Archive_Session @SessionGUID = 1
```

Returns

```
before raiserror
Msg 50000, Level 18, State 1, Procedure Archive_Session, Line 7
this is a raised error
```

Comment: this does seem a cleaner/faster way to type it out.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a lot of code but the best way i've found to do it.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE Procedure
    AS

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC AnotherProcedure
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

        SELECT 
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                   @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                   @ErrorState -- State.
                   );
        RETURN --this forces it out
    END CATCH

--Stuff here that you do not want to execute if the above failed.    

    END --end procedure
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have no `BEGIN` and `END` statements.  You shouldn't be seeing the prints, or errors running this statement, only `Statement Completed` (or something like that).